# Edges are missed by osm2po when imported to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis, pgrouting

I am using osm2po for importing pbf file to postgresql but when i find route using built-in algorithms i found that some of the edges are missing so route does not match with road. Did anybody know why this is happening, thanks in advance
Example is shown in this [image](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=c4e807b538d78e2f&id=C4E807B538D78E2F!1493)

Comment: Routing engine of osm2po is giving excellent results with very good ground resolution but when i import sql file to postgresql and view all edges i realizes many of the nodes or edges are missed and route generated not lies on road, i don't know may be it is related with tilesize of osm2po, if you have any idea please tell me

Comment: I'm sorry usually people use pgrouting or OSRM, osm2po has a very small community, so you might want to consult it directly http://osm2po.de

Comment: i am also using pgrouting but to convert osm data to sql i am using osm2po and in resulting sql file most of the edges are misses as shown in the image above

Comment: Thank you all and especially C.Moeller, i was using x1,y1,x2,y2 for rendering thus missing the geometry in my route. Now i can generated smooth route by using geom_way column